# How to make this SELECT Query in DELETE Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Query:

```
SELECT accounts.id, accounts.email FROM accounts
INNER JOIN (SELECT email FROM accounts
GROUP BY email HAVING count(id) > 1) dup ON accounts.email = dup.email
```

I need the results of this query are deleted. 
how to transform this query DELETE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE a.* FROM accounts a
JOIN (SELECT email
      FROM accounts
      GROUP BY email
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) dup
ON a.email = dup.email
```